# Using locally defined calculator commands inside tables (tabularx)

Tags: tables, calculations

Inside a table, I want to draw rules. Their length equals the cell length times a predefined ratio (i.e. `\rule{\ratio\linewidth}{1ex}`). I use the `\DIVIDE{A}{B}{\ratio}` function of the `calculator`-package that defines `\ratio` equal to the numeric value of A/B.

This works well if the ratio is defined outside the table. Yet, it bugs (with `! Undefined control sequence.` as error message) if I define the ratio within the table.

Here is an example with a locally defined ratio in the last line only (see MWE).
[image]

**Question:** Is there a way to locally define and use a calculated value using `calculator` within a table? *(I've tried to fiddle with `\expandafter` but with no success since I've reach there the limit of my TeX-skills)*

---

MWE which compilation bugs if you uncomment the two last lines of the table.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{calculator}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \COPY{1}{\numberA}
    \COPY{2}{\numberB}
        \DIVIDE{\numberA}{\numberB}{\ratioOne}

    \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{|l|l|l|X|}
        \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{A/B} & \textbf{Relative rule}
        \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & \rule{\linewidth}{1ex}
        \\
        \numberA & \numberB & \ratioOne & \rule{\ratioOne\linewidth}{1ex}
        \\
        %\numberA & \numberB & \DIVIDE{\numberA}{\numberB}{\ratioTwo} \ratioTwo& \rule{\ratioTwo\linewidth}{1ex}
        %\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

### Edit

Based on Christian's comment, I've found that if you define the ratio *within* the cell you use it, it compiles without error.
(I.e. following line causes no error.)

```
\numberA & \numberB & \DIVIDE{\numberA}{\numberB}{\ratioTwo} \ratioTwo& \DIVIDE{\numberA}{\numberB}{\ratioThree}\rule{\ratioThree\linewidth}{1ex}\\
```

Comment: I think you struggle here with the `cell` grouping -- the value in one cell does not make it to other cell

Comment: Indeed, since the cell `\DIVIDE{\numberA}{\numberB}{\ratioTwo} \ratioTwo` prints `0.5` as expected, and without causing an error during the compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all commands defined by calculator have local behavior (his scope is restricted into groups). This is the reason because \ratioTwo is undefined when you change to another column in your tabularx environment.

Use the \GLOBALCOPY command to globalize your number:

```
\GLOBALCOPY{\ratioTwo}{\ratioTwo}
```

(note than you can assign the same name to the new global number).

Try this version of your code:

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}
     \usepackage{calculator}
     \usepackage{tabularx}

 \begin{document}
 \COPY{1}{\numberA}
 \COPY{2}{\numberB}
    \DIVIDE{\numberA}{\numberB}{\ratioOne}

 \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{|l|l|l|X|}
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{A/B} & \textbf{Relative rule}
    \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & \rule{\linewidth}{1ex}
    \\
    \numberA & \numberB & \ratioOne & \rule{\ratioOne\linewidth}{1ex}
    \\
    \numberA & \numberB & \DIVIDE{\numberA}{\numberB}{\ratioTwo}
    \GLOBALCOPY{\ratioTwo}{\ratioTwo} \ratioTwo& \rule{\ratioTwo\linewidth}{1ex}
    \\
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{document}
```

But, why not define a new command to calculate ratio and print the tabular line? You can then write something like this:

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}
     \usepackage{calculator}
     \usepackage{tabularx}

 \begin{document}

 \newcommand{\maketableline}[2]{%
      \GLOBALCOPY{#1}{\numberA}
      \GLOBALCOPY{#2}{\numberB}
        \DIVIDE{\numberA}{\numberB}{\ABratio}
        \GLOBALCOPY{\ABratio}{\ABratio}
          \numberA & \numberB & \ABratio & \rule{\ABratio\linewidth}{1ex}\\
         }

 \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{|l|l|l|X|}
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{A/B} & \textbf{Relative rule}
    \\
    \maketableline{1}{1}
    \maketableline{1}{2}
    \maketableline{2}{3}
    \maketableline{3}{4}
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: `\GLOBALCOPY` was what I was looking for indeed! Thank you. Btw, this lead to a following question: [Mysterious summing: when calculator 's \ADD macro adds too much inside a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304402/64454) (-;

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with a wrapper for the `\DIVIDE` command, defining a `\ratio#3` command, where `#3` is the 3rd argument, say `Two` etc. It's a global command then, however, but survives the tabular cell.

Using a `toks` register could be an alternative.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\newratio}[3]{%
  \DIVIDE{#1}{#2}{\radioInt}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname ratio#3\endcsname{\radioInt}%
}

\begin{document}
    \COPY{1}{\numberA}
    \COPY{2}{\numberB}
    \DIVIDE{\numberA}{\numberB}{\ratioOne}
    \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{|l|l|l|X|}
        \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{A/B} & \textbf{Relative rule}
        \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & \rule{\linewidth}{1ex}
        \\
        \numberA & \numberB & \ratioOne & \rule{\ratioOne\linewidth}{1ex}
        \\
        \numberA & \numberB & \newratio{\numberA}{\numberB}{Two}\ratioTwo & \rule{\ratioTwo\linewidth}{1ex}
        \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll try to, little by little, understand your answer. Thank you! (Maybe I should have been more explicit in my long-term goal: I want to define a function that takes `A` as argument, and that computes a whole table row using a globally defined `B` value. It thus assesses the ratio for each line. So I'll figure out how to implement your answer in my real-case problem!)

Comment: @ebo: This possible with `\noalign{...}` etc or using `expl3`, but my answer just makes `\ratio....` available for all following table cells, using an `\xdef..` (you need `\xdef` to store the value of `\ratioInt (the internal value)`) An ordinary `\gdef` would not be sufficient here